# "Should It be" Or "It Should Be" - What is the correct order?

Tags: word-order

Are there grammar rules that indicate one of these two sentences has an incorrect word order? Is it possibly irrelevant in this case?

> 1. We'd like to know what is its purpose, and when **it should be** used.
> 2. We'd like to know what is its purpose, and when **should it be** used.

Answer (score 1):

This is a case of question within statement.

> what should I say? I don't know! ==>
>   I don't know what I should say.

this is the case even if you have a coordinating conjunction (such as **and** in your case)

> what should I say? How will he react? I don't know! ==>
>   I don't know what I should say and How he will react.

Therefore, I'd say:

> We'd like to know what its purpose is, and when it should be used.

is grammatical.

Answer (score 0):

The order of an English sentence is (subject , verb , object) and it's inverted when we want to ask a question and also in other very specific cases.

The sentence returns to normal order when it's not used as a question anymore .

*for example :*

What is you name ? *(inverted)*
I don't know what **your name is.** *(normal)*

What is its purpose ? *(inverted)*
 We'd like to know what **its purpose is.** *(normal)*

When should it be used ? *(inverted)*
We'd like to know when **it should be used.** *(normal)*.

Comment: So in fact both sentences are wrong; they should read "We'd like to know what its purpose is..."